# Logger Method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please explain me about the logger method in ruby on rails. And give one example with brief description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+logger

Comment: For those who googled that and wound up here. This is what you're looking for http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

logger is a method to write to your current environment's log.

`logger.debug "hi, i'm a debug message"`

You can also create custom instances.

```
log = Logger.new 'log/custom.log'
log.debug "hi, i'm a debug message"
```

And as @zsquare suggested: http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+logger

Comment: To the one downvoting me: Yes, the question is not optimal, but I answered what he wanted to know, so your downvote is inappropriate.